# Is it impossible to specialize non-static members in a class template? Why?

Tags: c++, templates

### Background

I have a class that I've templatized to get compile-time polymorphism as a alternative to run-time polymorphism through inheritance.

I have two different specializations of some of the methods in this class. Let's call them `T_a` and `T_b`.

### Problem

I want to initialize a const, yet non-static array of objects of this class with different values based on the template parameter.

```
template<class T>
class A {
    const anotherObject& aO;
    const ConfigPar configPars[];
}
```

### Non-working attempts

#### Specialization

First, I thought I could just specialize the member:

```
template<class T>
class A {
    const ConfigPar configPars[];

    A(T t);
}

template<>
const ConfigPar A<T_a>::configPars[] {
        {anotherObject.foo1, "bar1"},
        {anotherObject.foo2, "bar2"},
}

template<>
const ConfigPar A<T_b>::configPars[] {
        {anotherObject.foo1, "bar1"},
        {anotherObject.foo2, "bar2"},
        {anotherObject.foo3, "bar3"},
}
```

However, this doesn't work, since apparently you can only specialize static class members. However, the values of the objects in the `configPars` array depend on another instance member, so I can't make `configPars` static.

#### Constructor overloading

Next, I thought about overloading `A`'s constructor, and just initializing `configPars` differently in the constructors:

```
template<class T>
class A {
    const ConfigPar configPars[];

    A(T_a t) : configPars{
            {anotherObject.foo1, "bar1"},
            {anotherObject.foo2, "bar2"},
    } {}

    A(T_b t) : configPars{
            {anotherObject.foo1, "bar1"},
            {anotherObject.foo2, "bar2"},
            {anotherObject.foo3, "bar3"},
    } {}
}
```

However, in this my compiler complains that `error: too many initializers for 'const ConfigPar [0]'`. Apparently I can't leave the size of the array out in its declaration?

The problem is that the array sizes differ between the two specializations (or overloaded constructors, in this case).

How do I handle this?

Comment: `const ConfigPar configPars[];` is not legal.  All class members must have a defined size, meaning the array size must be known in the class definition.  You could use a `const std::vector<ConfigPar>` in its place.

Comment: @NathanOliver I see. Is there no way to define the size depending on the template parameter, e.g. in a specialisation? This is embedded (running on a microcontroller) so unfortunately I don't have access to the `std::` containers of the Standard Library.

Answer (score 3):

The size of all class members must be known inside the class definition.  This includes the size of the array member.  What you can do is determine what size array you have based on what `T` is and supply that in the definition.  That could look like

```
template<class T>
class A {
    const ConfigPar configPars[(std::is_same_v<T, T_a> ? 2 : 3)]; // 2 for T_a, 3 otherwise

    A(T t);
};

// specialization of constructor for T_a
template<>
A<T_a>::A(T_a t) : configPars{
        {1, "bar1"},
        {2, "bar2"},
}
{
    // constructor body, use t here
}

// specialization of constructor for T_b
template<>
A<T_b>::A(T_b t) : configPars{
        {1, "bar1"},
        {2, "bar2"},
        {3, "bar3"},
}
{
    // constructor body, use t here
}
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution, however, this is embedded so unfortunately `type_traits` isn't available to me. (sorry, forgot to mention that in my question)

Comment: @Compizfox Good news is, you don't need them.  `std::is_same` is easily implementable yourself.  There is even an implementation that you can copy from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).